# How does Facebook check if email exist within less than one second?

Tags: php, sql, linux

I'm always wondering how these big companies works!

It's like they've 1 Billion account in the DB and they check if a value exist in the database.

Comment: Like [hashing](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55471/what-exactly-and-precisely-is-hash/55472) and [trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure))?

Answer (score 0):

They can create a hash of your email address for very fast database lookups.  You can find more information about collisions detection and hash tables.

Comment: I don't think OP wants to know about email validation. It's about to check that same email exist.

Comment: Well, if you're referring to email addresses, I think I have answered that: They don't check because there is no mechanism to do such a check.

Comment: It's about the existence of same email in DB. like if I create a new account at fb with email so@so.com and if it exists in there DB. They'll throw an error that the same email exist in there DB try new one. and what you've answered has nothing to do with the question

Comment: Ah, collision detection.  I understand the question now.